# Dynamically add UI elements and gather their input in a dataframe in shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

My `ui.R` function is as shown below.

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Add Features"),
  sidebarPanel(width=4,
  fluidRow( 
  column(6,  selectInput("features", label = h3("Features"), 
  choices = list("Feature1","Feature2","Feature3"), selected = "Feature1")),    

  br(),
  br(),
  column(6,  numericInput("n", label="",min = 0, max = 100, value = 50)),
  br(),
  column(2, actionButton("goButton", "Add!"))
  #column(3, submitButton(text="Analyze"))
)),


mainPanel(
verbatimTextOutput("nText"),
textOutput("text2")
)
))
```

My `server.R` function is as below:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 selFeatures <- data.frame()
  valFeatures <- data.frame()
  # builds a reactive expression that only invalidates 
  # when the value of input$goButton becomes out of date 
  # (i.e., when the button is pressed)
  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {

    selFeatures <- rbind(selFeatures,input$features)
    valFeatures <- rbind(valFeatures,input$n)
    paste("The variables are",input$features,input$n)
    paste("The variables are",selFeatures,valFeatures)
    })

    output$nText <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
   output$text2 <- renderText({ 
     paste("You have selected", input$features)
   })
})
```

What I want to do is ask user to input some variables. Here `Feature1`, `Feature2`, and `Feature3`. User has to input `Feature1` but `Feature2` and `Feature3` are optional. So, here user selects a feature, inputs its value in `numericInput` and presses button `Add`. When `Add` is pressed after selecting `Feature1`, user can select to submit the form or add features 2 and 3 using the add button. I finally, want to use these three variables to learn a prediction model. How can I collect all the imputed information in the dataframe to process it. Also, if possible to remove `Feature1` from the `selectBox` after it has been added. I want my UI to look like the following before Pressing the add button[image]

and it should look like the following  after pressing the add button.

[image]

The feature1 here need not be in the select box, just a way to display that it has been added is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't quite sure why you wanted to use `selectInputs` for setting the variable values so here's a general example on how to access inputs from dynamically generated content:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Add Features"),
  sidebarPanel(width=4,
               fluidRow(column(12,
                               h3('Features'),
                               uiOutput('uiOutpt')
               )), # END fluidRow
               fluidRow(
                 column(4,div()),
                 column(4,actionButton("add", "Add!")),
                 column(4,actionButton('goButton',"Analyze"))
               ) # END fluidRow
  ), # END sidebarPanel
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("nText"),
    textOutput("text2"),
    tableOutput('tbl')
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  features <- reactiveValues(renderd=c(1))

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    out <- lapply(features$renderd,function(i){
      fv <- paste0('numInp_',i)
      vn <- paste0('Feature',i)
      # Get input values by namw
      sprintf( 'Variable: %s, Value: %5.3f',input[[vn]],input[[fv]] )
    })
    do.call(paste,c(out,sep="\n"))
  })

  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    out <- lapply(features$renderd,function(i){
      fv <- paste0('numInp_',i)
      vn <- paste0('Feature',i)
      data.frame(Variable=input[[vn]], Value=input[[fv]] )
    })
    do.call(rbind,out)
  })

  output$nText <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
  output$text2 <- renderText({ 
    sprintf("You have selected feature: %s", paste(features$renderd,collapse=", "))
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    df()
  })

  # Increment reactive values used to store how may rows we have rendered
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    if (max(features$renderd) > 2) return(NULL)
    features$renderd <- c(features$renderd, max(features$renderd)+1)
  })

  # If reactive vector updated we render the UI again
  observe({
    output$uiOutpt <- renderUI({
      # Create rows
      rows <- lapply(features$renderd,function(i){
        fluidRow(
          column(6,  selectInput(paste0('Feature',i), 
                                 label = "", 
                                 choices = list("Feature1","Feature2","Feature3"), 
                                 selected = paste0('Feature',i))),   
          column(6,  numericInput(paste0('numInp_',i), label="",min = 0, max = 100, value = runif(1,max=100)))
        )
      })
      do.call(shiny::tagList,rows)

    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I'm simply storing the ID's of the dynamically generated content in a vector that helps me keep track of what I've generated. To access the values i simply reconstruct the elements ID from the numbers stored in the vector.

Comment: How do I make a dataframe of feature and variable like:
Feature1 \t Feature2 \n 
55.45  \t              77.68 \n

Assign it to some variable name and plot a barplot for example?

Comment: I've added how you can get the values in a `data.frame` int he answer.

Comment: Sorry to bug but once more. Once I have entered in the value in the first feature and when I press Add button, the value in the first feature is lost, how do I make that permanent before Analyze is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Oskar's answer was very useful to me for a similar challenge I faced; for unlimited features, I figured out how to enable a "remove" button and to keep values when pressing the "add" button.  For posterity, here are my modifications to Oskar's code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Add Features"),
  sidebarPanel(width=4,
               fluidRow(column(12,
                               h3('Features'),
                               uiOutput('uiOutpt')
               )), # END fluidRow
               fluidRow(
                 column(4,div()),
                 column(4,actionButton("add", "Add!")),
                 column(4,actionButton("remove", "Remove!")),
                 column(4,actionButton('goButton',"Analyze"))
               ) # END fluidRow
  ), # END sidebarPanel
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text2"),
    tableOutput('tbl')
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  features <- reactiveValues(renderd=c(1),
                             conv=c(50),
                             inlabels=c('A'),
                             outlabels=c('B'))

  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    out <- lapply(features$renderd,function(i){
      fv <- paste0('numInp_',i)
      vn <- paste0('InLabel',i)
      data.frame(Variable=input[[vn]], Value=input[[fv]] )
    })
    do.call(rbind,out)
  })

  output$nText <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
  output$text2 <- renderText({ 
    paste(sprintf("You have selected feature: %s", paste(features$renderd,collapse=", ")))
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    df()
  })

  # Increment reactive values array used to store how may rows we have rendered
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    out <- lapply(features$renderd,function(i){
      fv <- paste0('numInp_',i)
      vn <- paste0('InLabel',i)
      vo <- paste0('OutLabel',i)
      data.frame(inlabels=input[[vn]],outlabels=input[[vo]], conv=input[[fv]] )
    })
    df<-do.call(rbind,out)
    print(df)
    features$inlabels <- c(as.character(df$inlabels),' ')
    features$outlabels <- c(as.character(df$outlabels),' ')
    print(c(features$inlabels,features$outlabels))

    features$renderd <- c(features$renderd, length(features$renderd)+1)
    print(features$renderd)
    print(names(features))
    features$conv<-c(df$conv,51-length(features$renderd))
  })

  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    features$renderd <- features$renderd[-length(features$renderd)]
  })

  # If reactive vector updated we render the UI again
  observe({
    output$uiOutpt <- renderUI({
      # Create rows
      rows <- lapply(features$renderd,function(i){
        fluidRow(
          # duplicate choices make selectize poop the bed, use unique():
          column(4,  selectizeInput(paste0('InLabel',i), 
                                 label = 'Input Name',selected=features$inlabels[i],
                                 choices=unique(c(features$inlabels[i],features$outlabels[!features$outlabels %in% features$inlabels])),
                                 options = list(create = TRUE))),
          column(4,  sliderInput(paste0('numInp_',i), label="Conversion",min = 0, max = 100, value = features$conv[i])),
          column(4, selectizeInput(paste0('OutLabel',i), 
                                label = "Output Name", selected=features$outlabels[i],
                                choices=unique(c(features$inlabels,features$outlabels)),
                                options = list(create = TRUE)))
        )
      })
      do.call(shiny::tagList,rows)
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```